# Type error with react-query and UseQueryResult

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am using react-query in my TS project:

useOrderItemsForCardsInList.ts:

```
import { getToken } from '../../tokens/getToken';
import { basePath } from '../../config/basePath';
import { getTokenAuthHeaders } from '../../functions/sharedHeaders';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

async function getOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID: string) {
    const token = await getToken();
    const response = await fetch(`${basePath}/lists/${listID}/order_items/`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: getTokenAuthHeaders(token)
    });

    return response.json();
}

export default function useOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID: string) {
    if (listID != null) {
        return useQuery(['list', listID], () => {
            return getOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID);
        });
    }
}
```

I use my query result over here:

```
import { useCardsForList } from '../../hooks/Cards/useCardsForList';
import useOrderItemsForCardsInList from '../../hooks/Lists/useOrderItemsForCardsInList';
import usePaginateCardsInList from '../../hooks/Cards/usePaginateCardsInList';

export default function CardsListFetch({ listID }: { listID: string }) {
    const { isLoading, isError, error, data } = useCardsForList(listID);
    const { orderItems } = useOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID);
    const pagesArray = usePaginateCardsInList(orderItems, data);

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

However, on my `const { orderItems } = useOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID);` line, I get the following error:

`Property 'orderItems' does not exist on type 'UseQueryResult<any, unknown> | undefined'.`

How can I resolve this? I don't really know how to consume the result of my query on Typescript, any help is be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property on `useQuery` that you need to consume where you find your data is called `data`, so it should be:

```
const { data } = useOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID);
```

if that `data` has a property called `orderItems`, you can access it from there.

However, two things I'm seeing in your code:

1. a conditional hook call of useQuery (which is forbidden in React)
2. your queryFn returns `any` because `fetch` is untyped, so even though you are using TypeScript, you won't get any typesafety that way.

Comment: The first thing I get why is the case, and in fact, it made the error dissapear alongside the `const { data }`, however, how can I solve the second point? Sorry, I'm still new to TS

Comment: You need to add a return type to the getOrderItemsForCardsInList function

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React with `react-query`, I suggest you install this devDependency called: "**@types/react-query**". When using VS Code or any other smart text editor that will help, because it will help you with type suggestions.

`npm i --save-dev @types/react-query`

Then go to your code and fix couple things:

- remove condition from `useOrderItemsForCardsInList()`. Don’t call React Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. See [React hooks rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).
- import `UseCategoryResult` and define interface for your return object. You can call it `OrderItemsResult` or similar. Add type `OrderType` with the fields of the order object or just use `orderItems: any` for now.
- Add return type `UseQueryResult<OrderItemsResult>` to `useOrderItemsForCardsInList()` function.
- Fix return value of `getOrderItemsForCardsInList()`, it should not be `response.json()` because that would be `Promise`, not actual data. Instead use `await response.json()`.
- So your function `useOrderItemsForCardsInList()` will return `UseQueryResult` which has properties like `isLoading`, `error` and `data`. In your second code snipper, you already use `data` in one place, so instead rename data to `orderData` and make sure you define default `orderItems` to empty array to avoid issues: `data: orderData = {orderItems: []}`

useOrderItemsForCardsInList.ts:

```js
import { getToken } from '../../tokens/getToken';
import { basePath } from '../../config/basePath';
import { getTokenAuthHeaders } from '../../functions/sharedHeaders';
import { useQuery, UseCategoryResult } from 'react-query';

type OrderType = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    // whatever fields you have.
}

interface OrderItemsResult {
  orderItems: OrderType[],
}

async function getOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID: string) {
    const token = await getToken();
    const response = await fetch(`${basePath}/lists/${listID}/order_items/`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: getTokenAuthHeaders(token)
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

export default function useOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID: string): UseQueryResult<OrderItemsResult> {
    return useQuery(['list', listID], () => {
        return getOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID);
    });
}
```

Use your query result:

```js
import { useCardsForList } from '../../hooks/Cards/useCardsForList';
import useOrderItemsForCardsInList from '../../hooks/Lists/useOrderItemsForCardsInList';
import usePaginateCardsInList from '../../hooks/Cards/usePaginateCardsInList';

export default function CardsListFetch({ listID }: { listID: string }) {
    const { isLoading, isError, error, data } = useCardsForList(listID);
    const { data: orderData = { orderItems: []}} = useOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID);
    const pagesArray = usePaginateCardsInList(orderItems, data);

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```